# Decimal point in sans serif font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif

For some reason, when I use `\mathsf{}`, the decimal point doesn't seem to be affected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsf{This is an example.} $ \mathsf{\frac{1}{2} = 0.5} $

The rest of the document is in normal serif font.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you look carefully, you can notice how the dot after 'example' is a square, but the dot between 0 and 5 is a circle.

This might not be a big deal in English, but in other languages where we use the comma instead of the dot this is much more noticeable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\textsf{This is an example,} $ \mathsf{\frac{1}{2} = 0.5} $

The rest of the document is in normal serif font.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[spanish]{babel} \spanishdecimal{\textsf{,}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected, because the period has type `\mathord`, so it doesn't change with `\mathXY` commands. However, it's easily fixed.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`.}
```

For the comma it's not as easy, because we can't assign the comma the `\mathalpha` type, since it should be punctuation.

It's easier to use `sansmath`, that also makes sans serif many other symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\newcommand{\sftextandmath}{\sffamily\sansmath}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\allsf}{\sftextandmath}

\begin{document}
\allsf{This is an example: $\frac{1}{2} = 0.5$}

This is another example: $\frac{1}{2}=0.5$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`spanish` from babel, defines a particular macro to alter the *output* of a decimal point (*i.e.*, you input, as *always*, a dot `.`, and you change the output with this macro).

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\spanishdecimal{\textsf{,}}
```

Personally, I like the dot itself, so `\spanishdecimal{.}` would do for me (there are other concrete macros for the dot or the comma, but `\spanishdecimal` is more general).

Comment: What about math in serif type?

Comment: I didn't think he needed, but `\spanishdecimal{\textsf{,}}` can be used inside a group, or appended to a macro. or whatever.

Comment: I did need it, I guess I should've been clearer. How would I use it inside a group (e.g. in egreg's example)?

Comment: @saarl Possible, but since egreg already answered, I think the `sansmath` is more general.